# Appending 0 (zero) to a grep match reference

Tags: regex, reference, zero, bbedit

#### tl;dr

I want to add a `0` at the end of the first backreference (`\1`) from a grep search. How can I differentiate this from the *tenth* backreference (`\10`).

---

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) in [bbedit](/questions/tagged/bbedit), I want to replace a part of a string with a part of that part of a string and a zero.

For example, find and replace this part of a string:

```
195.22.126.x
```

in this string:

```
195.22.126.x - - [13/Jul/2018:19:16:49 -0200] "GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 243
```

with part of that part of a string and a zero:

```
195.22.126.0
```

If I wanted to replace the "x" at the end of that part of a string with a "y", the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) code would look like this:

```
Find:
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)x

Replace:
\1y
```

But if I want to replace the "x" with a "0" (zero), the program tries to extract the *tenth* match, instead of appending a zero to the first match, because `\10` looks like "tenth match" to it, not like "first match and a zero".

So how do I append a zero to a grep match?

---

Please note that I cannot simply replace "x" with "0", because there are other "x"s in the string. Therefore I have to match the correct part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Do this:

```
Find:
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)x

Replace:
\010
```

From the manual:

> If more than two decimal digits follow the backslash, only the first
>   two are considered part of the backreference. Thus, “\111” would be
>   interpreted as the 11th backreference, followed by a literal “1”. You
>   may use a leading zero; for example, if in your replacement pattern you
>   want the first backreference followed by a literal “1”, you can use
>   “\011”. (If you use “\11”, you will get the 11th backreference, even if
>   it is empty.)

---

Well, if this is the actual string you want to work with, there’s a
simple solution: just move the last dot out of the group.

```
Find:
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.x

Replace:
\1.0
```

If you want to replace something else where this workaround doesn’t
work, another simple workaround would be like this:

```
First find:
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)x

First replace:
\1zzfoobarzz0

Second find:
zzfoobarzz

Second replace:
(empty)
```

Where `zzfoobarzz` is some such weird string that appears nowhere in the
file. Ugly but workable.

Another idea would be to use a lookbehind assertion to match
`195.22.126.`, leaving it out of the group. It would not be replaced,
that way.

Comment: You are right about moving the dot out of the group. I didn't think of that when I came up with my example. But your edit gave me what I wanted (`\010`). Thank you for that. And for those who wonder: That's the BBEdit User Manual.